# CSS fix positioning of anchors next to details summary

Tags: html, css, hugo

I'm working on my Hugo site (repo [here](https://github.com/levicrews/academic-website)). I want to add a details element next to anchors, all styled to look the same, as shown in the first screenshot ("abstract" is the details element that reveals the abstract when clicked; "paper" and "slides" are links to PDFs).

[image]

But when the details element is open, this pushes the anchors below the text of the abstract, as shown in the second screenshot.

[image]

**Is it possible to keep the anchors in their position from the first screenshot when the details element is open?**

Here's the markup for the page:

```
## working papers

1. **A dynamic spatial knowledge economy** (JMP) <br>
    <details>

    <summary>abstract</summary>

    Cities have long been thought to drive economic growth. ...

    </details>
    <a href="/files/p-dske_paper.pdf" class="button">paper</a>
    <a href="/files/p-dske_slides.pdf" class="button">slides</a>
```

And here's the custom CSS I'm currently hacking on (would go in `static/css/custom.css`):

```
details {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
summary {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border: none;
    color: #2774AE;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
summary:hover {
    background: #FFC72C;
}
details>summary {
    list-style: none;
}
details>summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
}
details[open] summary {
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.button {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border: none;
    color: #2774AE;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* rounded corners */
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #FFC72C;
    color: #2774AE;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to move any of the html around?

Comment: @Bjorn.B, yes definitely

Comment: Great! Sometimes people don't have control of the content but don't specify in their question. I just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the trigger and links together, and have the content live outside of that group. Then using JS, you can toggle visibility of that content using an event listener, the event being the mouse click.

### Update:

Initially I wasn't sure if you needed this to support multiple sections, and it looks like you do. The way this is set up is that the button triggers (inside nav) have an attribute called `data-nav` followed by a number. If you look inside the details div, there are content blocks that have an attribute called `data-summary` followed by a number. The JS will watch for the button triggers to be clicked. Once they are, it will take that `data-nav` number, and check for details div's with the same number assigned to the `data-summary` attribute. If it already has `.show` that makes it visible, then it will remove it. If it doesn't have that class, then it will remove that class from all of the other items (in case it's active somewhere else) and then add it to the one you just clicked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('nav .summary').forEach(function(summary) {
  summary.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dataAtt = this.getAttribute('data-nav');
    var matchTarg = document.querySelector('.summary-target[data-summary="' + dataAtt + '"]');
    
    if (matchTarg.classList.contains('show')) {
      matchTarg.classList.remove('show');
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.summary-target').forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove('show');
      });
      matchTarg.classList.add('show');
    }
  });
});


/*$('nav .summary').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    var $dataAtt = $(this).attr('data-nav');
    var $matchTarg = $('.summary-target[data-summary="'+$dataAtt+'"]');
    
    if( $matchTarg.hasClass('show') ){
      $matchTarg.removeClass('show');
    } else {
      $('.summary-target').removeClass('show');
      $matchTarg.addClass('show');
    }
  });
});*/
```

```css
.details {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.details .summary-target {
    display: none;
}
.details .summary-target.show {
    display: block;
}

nav {
  user-select: none;
}
nav * {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.summary {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border: none;
    color: #2774AE;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.summary:hover {
    background: #FFC72C;
}
nav .summary {
    list-style: none;
}
nav .summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
}
nav .summary {
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.button {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border: none;
    color: #2774AE;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* rounded corners */
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #FFC72C;
    color: #2774AE;
}
```

```html
<h1>A dynamic spatial knowledge economy** (JMP)</h1>
<nav>
  <div class="summary" data-nav="1">abstract 1</div>
  <div class="summary" data-nav="2">abstract 2</div>
  <div class="summary" data-nav="3">abstract 3</div>
  <a href="/files/p-dske_paper.pdf" class="button">paper</a>
  <a href="/files/p-dske_slides.pdf" class="button">slides</a>
</nav>

<div class="details">
  <div class="summary-target" data-summary="1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  </div>
  <div class="summary-target" data-summary="2">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div> 
  <div class="summary-target" data-summary="3">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I have it working for the first paper, but when I try to follow that HTML for the second paper (you can see it peeking out at the bottom of the second screenshot), the "abstract" button doesn't reveal anything upon being clicked.

Comment: @LeviCrews Ah I had wondered that. I just updated the code and the answer.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thanks a ton! One more quick question: before I could set `<details open>` to have the details element default to being open. How would I do that with this new setup?

Comment: Great! To have one open by default, just add the class “show” to any of the .summary-target divs, like class=“summary-target show”. The class show is what gives those divs its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag with an onclick event. but you have to use some JavaScript too.

```
 <button onclick="abstract()">abstract</button>
 <a href="/files/p-dske_paper.pdf" class="button">paper</a>
 <a href="/files/p-dske_slides.pdf" class="button">slides</a>
```

after use button you can add your other links

in javascript,

```
<script>
    function abstract(){    
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Cities have long been thought to drive economic growth. ..." ;
    }   
</script>
```

I hope you will get the output that you want.

more refer in here [Onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this would open the abstract upon clicking, but it wouldn't close it upon clicking again, which is a key feature of the details element. Is there a way to mimic that behavior in javascript?